# Unable to run bash script via UserData in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am launching an EC2 instance and when the instance is launched for the first time, I am trying to run a few commands and set a few environment variables using [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). The commands that I have added to the `UserData`:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ build-essential
sudo apt install -y zip awscli python3-pip python3.7 python3.7-dev
python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install virtualenv
mkdir anomaly-detection

export DB_ADAPTER=postgresql+psycopg2
export DB_USER=dummy_user
export DB_PASSWORD=dummy_pwd
export DB_HOST=ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
export DB_NAME=dummy_db
```

After the instance is launched, I launch the instance and when I check for the environment variables, they aren't set, also the `mkdir` command wasn't run. (So I am assuming that all the commands haven't been executed).

What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: It actually launches as a sub shell, so these env vars aren't accessible. I think you could try running the script with `. ./script/location/script.sh`. Notice the leading dot.

Comment: Hey @MarkoE, what would the location of the script be which has been written using userdata? Also, should I add the `. ./script/location/script.sh` command in the userdata?

Comment: If you're using Terraform, you can choose where to copy it. If you're doing it from the AWS console - don't. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to understand how can it be done. I am new to shell scripting, so it is confusing me. Once I enter the userdata, shouldn't the commands be automatically run when the instance is launched? Also, I am not using Terraform

Comment: Is your instance up & running? If so, you could go through the log file `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log ` and see which errors are there, if any. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @MarkoE Yep the instance is up & running. I checked the logfile and there are no errors.  Linux 18.04

Answer (score 1):

The User Data script is run as the `root` user.

If you wish to define environment variables for users that will exist when the login, you should define them in each user's `.profile` file. If you always login as `ec2-user`, then adding it to `/home/ec2-user/.profile` would be sufficient.

See: [How to permanently set environmental variables - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)